# How to start and stop a Thread with the same shortKey?

Tags: java, multithreading

Hello I want to make a if statement in JAVA, that..if thread is not running, we pressed a shortkey and the Thread start running, and if the thread is running, we pressed the same shortkey and the Thread stops running.

My code:

```
if(!th.isAlive()){
    th.start();
}else{
    th.stop();
    }
```

But doesn't work this code. Please help me.

p.s - This if statement happens when click in shortkey

Comment: You should call interrupt() method to stop thread and catch InterruptedException.

Comment: You should use interrupt():
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590000/what-does-java-lang-thread-interrupt-do

Comment: stop() method is depricated. Method start() you can call only once. Use some boolean flag & wait/notify to stop/re-run your code or more convinient primitives from java.util.concurrent

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: Before you do anything with Threads, you need to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop-- .  If there are any deprecated methods which should be avoided at all costs, they would be Thread.stop, Thread.resume, and Thread.suspend.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you should use `thread.interrupt()` it is because the thread dies when calling *stop()* and thus cannot be restarted. (see [How can a dead thread be restarted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223931/how-can-a-dead-thread-be-restarted))

You might be interested in [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to implement the behavior you are describing.